# How to setup Light Linking in blender 2.9 or 2.8x?

Tags: rendering, lighting

Coming from Maya background and a beginner in Blender 2.8x and 2.9.

I have a set of objects in the scene file and created separate lights for each object. I want to link lights to those objects specifically so that during render time the render engine only renders lights that are linked.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Blender doesn't have that feature. A huge amount of people asked for it for years, but nothing so far.